# Extracting next rows in Pandas Dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following Dataframe

```
  final  raw  act    wc             Start            Finish
   abc  xyz   30    M5  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  xyz   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  xyz   50    F6  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  xyz   60    F8  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  pqr   40  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   50   M12  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   60  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   20    F3  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  pqr   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  pqr   50    F6  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
```

I would like to take the two rows from here, one is

```
 abc  xyz   50  F6  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
```

another one is

```
abc  pqr   50    F6  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
```

The logic would be that for each **raw**, pick up the next row where **wc** is either *F3, F4* and the **act** is maximum. Here for *xyz*, *F4* is there, so the next row also for *pqr*, both *F3, F4* are there but maximum *act* is 40.

I did it using `pd.shift()`

```
dft = dfUno.loc[dfUno['wc'].shift().eq('F4')]
```

But I would like to see it in a more generic way, may be extracting using `iterrows()`. Like, my code is only true for *F4*. I want to extract the dataframe used for above *F4/ F3* also.

Expected outcome for this:

```
 final  raw  act    wc             Start            Finish
   abc  xyz   30    M5  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  xyz   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  pqr   40  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   50   M12  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   60  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
   abc  pqr   20    F3  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
   abc  pqr   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
```

pls suggest something, how to do it.

Comment: The method you have is great, do not use `iterrows()`   Maybe check out `isin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
ends = df[df.wc.isin(["F3", "F4"])].groupby("raw", sort=False).act.idxmax()

uniqs = ~df.raw.duplicated()
starts = uniqs[uniqs].index

out = df.iloc[np.r_[tuple(map(slice, starts, ends+1))]]
```

---

You can first subset the frame to only have rows with `wc` equal to `"F3"` or `"F4"`. Then group by the `raw` column to see which index per group gives a maximum `act`. These give the "end" locations for the selections:

```
>>> ends = df[df.wc.isin(["F3", "F4"])].groupby("raw", sort=False).act.idxmax()
>>> ends
raw
xyz    1
pqr    8
Name: act, dtype: int64
```

Now we need the "start" positions. `duplicated` function can be used to detect where each group in `raw` column starts:

```
>>> uniqs = ~df.raw.duplicated()
>>> uniqs
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: raw, dtype: bool

# get the locations of True's
>>> starts = uniqs[uniqs].index
>>> starts
Int64Index([0, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Now all we need to do is generate a dynamic slicer for the groups. For this, we `map` the starts & ends with `slice` object constructor and then pass it to `np.r_` as a tuple to keep them altogether:

```
# +1 so that we include endpoints
>>> slices = tuple(map(slice, starts, ends+1))
>>> slices
(slice(0, 2, None), slice(4, 9, None))

>>> rows_to_choose = np.r_[slices]
>>> rows_to_choose
array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

So the end result arises with `iloc` now

```
>>> df.iloc[rows_to_choose]
  final  raw  act    wc             Start            Finish
0   abc  xyz   30    M5  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
1   abc  xyz   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
4   abc  pqr   40  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
5   abc  pqr   50   M12  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
6   abc  pqr   60  M14S  17-01-2022 06:00  18-01-2026 17:21
7   abc  pqr   20    F3  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
8   abc  pqr   40    F4  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36
```

---

**Note 1**: The `sort=False` of `groupby` assures `raw` isn't sorted whilst grouping, otherwise we'd get the end position of the row with `"pqr"` first in `ends` since `"pqr" < "xyz"`, and that'd conflict with `starts`' ordering.

**Note 2**: The above assumes you have a RangeIndex, i.e., 0..N-1 kind of index. If this is not the case, you can copy it before and then put it back, i.e.,

```
orig_index = df.index
new_df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

... # above operations with `new_df`

out.index = orig_index[out.index]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your views. Can you throw some lights on the issue mentioned later. How to extract all the rows above the rows for F3/ F4.

Comment: Passing `"F3"` and `"F4"` to `isin` does that with `df.wc.isin(["F3", "F4"])` part, doesn't it? Can you clarify please?

Comment: I am not looking for ```isin(['F3', 'F4'])```. I can extract the rows where 'F3/ F4' exists. Rather I would like to take the Dataframe, which sat above of these rows along with this rows. Kindly check my last expected outcome.

Comment: Oh, I see... Sorry about not answering your question in the first place :) Let me think and get back to you.

Comment: @Manglu I *think* it works now. Sorry for the first misanswer.

Comment: ! It is nice way. Can you give your views on the 1st part where I have used ```dft = dfUno.loc[dfUno['wc'].shift().eq('F4')]```. I would like to take this ```F3/ F4```. If I use ```F3```, in ```dft = dfUno.loc[dfUno['wc'].shift().eq('F3')]```, I shall miss ```abc  xyz   50  F6  17-01-2022 06:00  14-07-2031 02:36```. How to do in a single step. I can do it by extracting and concatenating.

Comment: `dfUno.loc[dfUno["wc"].shift().isin(["F3", "F4"])]`?